# Setup individual Content-Security_Policy for grape-swagger-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

On my `rswag_ui.rb` I have the following.

```
module Rswag
  module Ui
    module CSP
      def call(env)
        _, headers, = response = super
        headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = <<~POLICY.gsub "\n", ' '
        default-src 'self';
        img-src 'self' data: https://online.swagger.io;
        font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com;
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
        connect-src 'self' http://localhost:3000;
      POLICY
    response
  end ...

Rswag::Ui::Middleware.prepend Rswag::Ui::CSP
```

I want to do the same for `grape-rails-swagger`, I need to add custom `Content-Security-Policy` on the swagger page.